# Unity tweak tool devices issue

Tags: unity, unity-tweak-tool

In the unity tweak tool, under desktop icons, there are options to make home folder, network, trash and devices appear on the desktop. All of those options work except devices.When I select the option nothing changes on my desktop and as soon as I leave that section of the tool it unselects it. I really want to be able to have my devices shown on the desktop. Any help is appreciated.

I am running Ubuntu 14.10 Utopic Unicorn 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

What it means by "Devices" is actually USB drives and other temporary drives/partitions. It does not mean regular hardware devices like graphics card etc.

To see if it works, try turning it on and then connect a USB thumb drive or external HDD/CD drive. If a new icon pops up, it works.

Comment: Yea sorry man USB drives and such is what I meant. I can get them to show up on my Docky but I would prefer them on my desktop.